# javascript array both index value getting update when I update only one index of that array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, multidimensional-array

Guys I have got into this problem while making dynamic multidimensional array and still I have no idea whats going wrong basically when I update that particular parent index of an array using javascript like

```
.on('click', function(){
     array[dynamicIndex] = anotherArray;
 });
```

So the problem is that when `array[53][1,2,3]` is first index assigned value in that but when I try to assign new value new index the array updated into

```
array[53][1,2,3,4,5,6]
array[54][1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

Hope you got the question if not you can visit this [link](http://jsfiddle.net/q4unjc2y/164/).

Comment: arrays are passed by reference, did you checked you're not assigning the same array ref to different elements in the parent array?

Comment: If you're using the same `anotherArray` every time, you're putting references to the same array in all elements.

Comment: No i am not assigning same array as i just want to assign the array in different index. You can visit the link for reference. @FrontTheMachine

Comment: I didn't get please explain @Barmar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When, in your example, you use:

```
lightArr[parseInt(thatText)] = minArray;
```

you are assigning an array by reference. In this way, any change you make to the `minArray` will be reflected to the `lightArr[parseInt(thatText)]` value.

You can use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7486130/7772490) approach to solve your problem:

```
lightArr[parseInt(thatText)] = minArray.slice();
```

Comment: Where did `lightArr`, `thatText`, and `minArray` come from? It seems like you got the code from a different question, although the explanation is right.

Comment: @Barmar they come from the jsfiddle link he provided.

Comment: Thanks a lot @omaxel what a beautiful and precise answer.